# Vectorize Matrix and vector operation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following code in Matlab.  I've never had to vectorize with a matrix involved.  Doing some research it seems I should use `bsxfun` but I'm having a hard trying to understand how it works in my example.  I've tried a few things but can't seem to figure it out.  Below is the non-vectorized code that runs and produces the output I want.

```
# W is 500 x 100 matrix
# delta is 100 x 1 vector
# alpha is scalar

for i = 1: 100
    W(:,i) = W(:, i) - (alpha * delta(i));
end
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
W = bsxfun(@minus, W, alpha*delta.');
```

This works as follows: `delta` is transformed into a row vector (`.'`) and multiplied by the scalar `alpha`. The obtained row vector is subtracted from each row of `W` using `bsxfun`. You can view `bsxfun` as an "implicit `repmat`": it replicates the row `alpha*Delta.'` as many times as needed to match the size of `W`; and then it does the subtraction (`@minus`).

Comment: appreciate the explanation!

Comment: @user2743 You'll find that `bsxfun` is very powerful, once you get used to it

Comment: After reviewing this shouldn't alpha Delta.' be subtracted from the columns of W like in my code example?

Comment: Your code example subtracts `alpha*delta.'` (which is a row vector) from each _row_ of `W`. You can check that your code and mine produce the same result